# How do I write a query to display the months between two dates?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database of IDs with income and start/end dates as below but I have trouble breaking the income per ID per month for the given start/end date range.

A sample of the table data is below:

```
ID | INCOME | START_DATE | END_DATE
 1 |   2000 | 02/01/2016 | 05/31/2016
 1 |   1500 | 12/01/2015 | 01/31/2016
 2 |   1000 | 01/01/2016 | 04/30/2016
```

The outcome should be:

```
ID | INCOME | MONTH
 1 |   2000 | 05/2016
 1 |   2000 | 04/2016
 1 |   2000 | 03/2016
 1 |   2000 | 02/2016
 1 |   1500 | 01/2016
 1 |   1500 | 12/2015
 2 |   1000 | 04/2016
 2 |   1000 | 03/2016
 2 |   1000 | 02/2016
 2 |   1000 | 01/2016
```

How would I write the Oracle SQL such that I am able to produce the above outcome efficiently (assuming the table has thousands of unique IDs)?

Comment: What version of Oracle database?

Comment: ?  Current Oracle version is 12, you surely are not on Oracle 3? To find out your version, run `select * from v$version;`

Comment: 11.2.0.4.0 I believe, 11g. Sorry.

Comment: Good news then - you can use either of the two answers you received. If you study them closely, you will learn two different techniques that you may be able to use in the future. Yes, your Oracle version is 11.2, and more specifically 11.2.0.4.0; 11g is the marketing name Oracle uses, but whenever you post it helps to add you are on 11.2 or better, 11.2.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using connect by, like so:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, 2000 income, to_date('01/02/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('31/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual union all
                     select 1 id, 1500 income, to_date('01/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual union all
                     select 2 id, 1000 income, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('30/04/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual)
select id,
       income,
       add_months(trunc(start_date, 'mm'), -1 + level) mnth
from   sample_data
connect by prior id = id
           and prior income = income
           and prior sys_guid() is not null
           and add_months(trunc(start_date, 'mm'), -1 + level) <= trunc(end_date, 'mm')
order by id, income desc, mnth desc;


        ID     INCOME MNTH     
---------- ---------- ---------
         1       2000 01-MAY-16
         1       2000 01-APR-16
         1       2000 01-MAR-16
         1       2000 01-FEB-16
         1       1500 01-JAN-16
         1       1500 01-DEC-15
         2       1000 01-APR-16
         2       1000 01-MAR-16
         2       1000 01-FEB-16
         2       1000 01-JAN-16
```

Comment: What's the purpose of "prior sys_guid() is not null"?

Comment: @Matt it stops Oracle from processing the rows more than is necessary, when there are multiple rows to process  If you exclude it, you’ll get lots of extra rows you (probably) don’t want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [recursive subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55268), if you're on 11gR2 or higher:

```
with r (id, income, this_date, end_date) as (
  select id, income, trunc(start_date, 'MM'), trunc(end_date, 'MM')
  from your_table
  union all
  select id, income, this_date + interval '1' month, end_date
  from r
  where end_date > this_date
)
select id, income, to_char(this_date, 'MM/YYYY') as month
from r
order by id, this_date desc;

        ID     INCOME MONTH 
---------- ---------- -------
         1       2000 05/2016
         1       2000 04/2016
         1       2000 03/2016
         1       2000 02/2016
         1       1500 01/2016
         1       1500 12/2015
         2       1000 04/2016
         2       1000 03/2016
         2       1000 02/2016
         2       1000 01/2016
```

The anchor member gets the starting information - which I'm truncating to the start of the month, probably redundantly, but just in case one starts late enough in the month to cause a problem with interval addition. The recursive member then keeps adding a month to each existing member until it reaches the end date.

Comment: If you have a lot of data check which performs better; I suspect connect-by will be slightly faster, though it can fail with large data volumes. (Well, so can this, I suppose, at some point!)